# Excel stays visible when changing desktop on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel-2010

I am using office 2010 on a windows 10 computer (upgraded from windows 7, office was installed prior to the upgrade)

I have a problem that occurs whenever I have two or more excel spreadsheats opened simultaneously. If I am looking at a spreadsheet and I change desktop, the active spreadsheat stays on foreground(wether by shortcut or by clicking the icon). This is frustrating since I always have to minimize the spreadsheet.

I do not have this behaviour if only one spreadsheat is opened. It is limited to excel (opening multiple word documents is fine).

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to prevent this behaviour?